# Google SDK Report dont get info

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api

I have a app in GAE. This belongs to a domain. This app get info from Reports Api.

If I ask for information 4 days ago, I get the information from doc and gmail. If I ask for information 3 days ago I get only the information of gmail.  If I ask for information **two days ago (1)** does not give me information.

But if I get info from (1) date in the future (eg: ten day) the Api get all info from this date.

The api has a delay when I get info?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://support.google.com/a/answer/6000239?hl=en&ref_topic=4639149

Short answer is that yes, there is a delay in when full report data is available. Some reports have lower latency than others and it is possible that you'll only get a subset of the expected report data back.

Comment: it's possible that UserUsageReport has a delay of ten days? In special with data from GDoc.